# In Cognitive search data is showing after Deletion.How to delete that data?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-services, soft-delete

I have opted for the free plan where I am using azure cognitive search along with azure cosmos Db. When I delete a product from the database, In the search result, It is still showing

I have set indexer to refresh in 5 min
also tried track deletion
Still, nothing is helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard deletes are not picked up by Azure Search. The only way to do this today is through soft deletes.

You can learn more in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb?toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json&bc=/azure/cosmos-db/breadcrumb/toc.json#indexing-deleted-documents)